# When writing an R package that uses the Matrix package, why do I have to specify Matrix::t() instead of just t()?

Tags: r, namespaces, sparse-matrix

Consider the following simple functions defined in an R session:

```
nathanvan@nathanvan-N61Jq:~$ R

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
... snip ... 
> make.a.Matrix <- function(data, nrow, ncol) {
+    require(Matrix)
+    return( Matrix(data, nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol))
+ }
> 
> transpose.a.Matrix <- function(data, nrow, ncol  ) {
+   return(t( make.a.Matrix(data, nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol) ))
+ }
> 
> make.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: lattice
3 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> transpose.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
4 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
```

If we put those same functions into a package, the `transpose.a.Matrix` function no longer works. *Since describing the package creation process would be too lengthy, I have simply posted a copy of the package [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/minimalbugexample_0.1.tar.gz). I have posted the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files at the end of the question. If other pieces are relevant, I'd be happy to post them too. Just let me know!*

```
nathanvan@nathanvan-N61Jq:~$ R

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
... snip ... 
> require(minimalbugexample)
Loading required package: minimalbugexample
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: testthat
> make.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
3 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> transpose.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
Error in t.default(make.a.Matrix(data, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)) : 
  argument is not a matrix
> transpose.a.Matrix
function(data, nrow, ncol  ) {
  return(t( make.a.Matrix(data, nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol) ))
}
<environment: namespace:minimalbugexample>
```

I think that the key here is something weird about the namespace. Notice that if I debug the function, I can manually call the `Matrix::t` and it will work while the `base::t` fails with the same error.

```
> debug(transpose.a.Matrix)
> transpose.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
debugging in: transpose.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
debug at /home/nathanvan/Ubuntu One/workspace/experimental-design/software/minimalbugexample/R/use-Matrix-package.R#31: {
    return(t(make.a.Matrix(data, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)))
}
Browse[2]> t(Matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
Error in t.default(Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)) : argument is not a matrix
Browse[2]> t
function (x) 
UseMethod("t")
<bytecode: 0x46b0a88>
<environment: namespace:base>
Browse[2]> Matrix::t(Matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
4 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
Browse[2]> base::t(Matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
Error in t.default(Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)) : argument is not a matrix
```

And yet using `showMethods`, it suggest that just using `t` should find the right one, even though it did not.

```
Browse[2]> showMethods('t')
Function: t (package base)
x="ANY"
x="CsparseMatrix"
x="dgeMatrix"
x="diagonalMatrix"
x="dppMatrix"
x="dsCMatrix"
x="dspMatrix"
x="dsTMatrix"
x="dsyMatrix"
x="dtpMatrix"
x="dtrMatrix"
x="dtTMatrix"
x="lgeMatrix"
x="lspMatrix"
x="lsTMatrix"
x="lsyMatrix"
x="ltpMatrix"
x="ltrMatrix"
x="ltTMatrix"
x="matrix"
    (inherited from: x="ANY")
x="Matrix"
x="ngeMatrix"
x="nspMatrix"
x="nsTMatrix"
x="nsyMatrix"
x="ntpMatrix"
x="ntrMatrix"
x="ntTMatrix"
x="pMatrix"
x="RsparseMatrix"
x="TsparseMatrix"
```

For now, I can “fix” it by editing the source for the package so that the `transpose.a.Matrix` function specifies that it needs the `Matrix::t` method:

```
transpose.a.Matrix <- function(data, nrow, ncol  ) {
  require(Matrix)
  return(Matrix::t( make.a.Matrix(data, nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol) ))
}
```

But that seems like it should not be needed. What am I missing?

My DESCRIPTION file is

```
Package: minimalbugexample
Title: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1
Author: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Maintainer: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Depends:
    R (>= 3.0.1),
    Matrix (>= 1.0),
    testthat
License: GPL
LazyData: true
Collate:
    'minimalbugexample-package.r'
    'use-Matrix-package.R'
```

My NAMESPACE file is

```
export(make.a.Matrix)
export(transpose.a.Matrix)
```

and I can post additional pieces upon request.

Comment: Try importing `t` from `Matrix` in your NAMESPACE.

Comment: The **Matrix** package uses S4 methods, which require some special attention to import and export. Have you read the section of the R-exts manual titled [Namespaces with S4 classes and methods](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods)?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I had not. I've got it working now. Would you like me to write up an answer, or would you prefer to? (so that you can get the 'accept'). Thanks!

Comment: @NathanVanHoudnos -- It would be great if you would write up the steps that worked. Thanks for taking the time to wrap this up that way!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Done. If you get a moment, could you check that my answer is, in fact, right?

Comment: @NathanVanHoudnos -- I can't really say, but it sounds like it worked for you, so that's good! (Learning how this works is one of those bridges I've figured I'll cross when and if I get to it. Now, thanks to you, I'll have some guideposts if I do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A working example on gitHub

[I put a working example on gitHub so that it is easy to browse the different files](https://github.com/nathanvan/minimalbugexample/tree/e6d62a6da7127fc165332935db04aa88b4575ae6).

FYI, it's not quite a minimal example since it was built with `devtools`. The "extras" are (1) that `roxygen2` comments are what builds the NAMESPACE file, and (2) it incorporates unit testing with `testthat`. All of that can be ignored for the purposes of this example.

### The key fix

The short answer that I did, in fact, need to change my NAMESPACE file to:

```
export(make.a.Matrix)
export(transpose.a.Matrix)
importFrom(Matrix,Matrix)
importFrom(Matrix,t)
```

So that R could find the right version of transpose. See this [post](http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) for a great description of how R searches for functions.

Although not strictly necessary, I modified my DESCRIPTION file to be a tad bit cleaner:

```
Package: minimalbugexample
Title: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1.3
Author: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Maintainer: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Depends:
    R (>= 3.0.1),
    Matrix (>= 1.0)
Suggests:
    testthat (>= 0.7.1.99)
License: GPL
LazyData: true
Collate:
    'minimalbugexample-package.r'
    'use-Matrix-package.R'
```

Note that I am using `Depends:` for `Matrix` instead of `Imports:` so that the user will be able to use the `Matrix` objects that the functions return. If this example only used the `Matrix` stuff internally without presenting it to the user, I'd have used `Imports:`.

### Proof that it works

```
> require(minimalbugexample)
> make.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
3 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> transpose.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
4 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
> t( make.a.Matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
4 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
```

Note that the last command would have failed if I had specified `Matrix` in `Imports:` and not `Depends:`.