# Can plot interaction means for nlme fit, but not for lme4

Tags: r, interaction, lmer, nlme

Using this dummy dataset:

```
dummy.data <- data.frame(vaccinated = factor(rep(c("yes", "no"), each = 64)),
  infected = factor(rep(c("yes", "no"), each = 32)),
  animal = factor(rep(1:16, each = 8)),
  tissue = factor(c("blood", "liver", "kidney", "brain")),
  value = runif(128)
  )
```

This works:

```
library("nlme")
nlme.model <- as.formula(value ~ vaccinated * infected * tissue)
nlme.fit <- lme(fixed = nlme.model, random = ~1|animal, data = dummy.data)
library("phia")
int.nlme <- interactionMeans(nlme.fit)
plot(int.nlme)
```

But this doesn't:

```
library("lme4")  
lmer.model <- as.formula(value ~ vaccinated * infected * tissue + (1 | animal))
lmer.fit <- lmer(formula = lmer.model, data = dummy.data)
library("phia")
int.lmer <- interactionMeans(lmer.fit)
plot(int.lmer)
```

With the latter, I only get

```
Error in t.default(M) : argument is not a matrix
```

from the `plot` command.

When I look at `int.nlme` and `int.lmer` with `str`, they do look different, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears to be generated from `phia:::poolse` and can be replicated thus:

```
> phia:::poolse(int.nlme, "adjusted mean","vaccinated")
vaccinated
        no        yes 
0.04483019 0.04483019 
> phia:::poolse(int.lmer, "adjusted mean","vaccinated")
Error in t.default(M) : argument is not a matrix
```

Still digging...

And I conclude its a bug in the `phia` package, which has neglected this:

[When writing an R package that uses the Matrix package, why do I have to specify Matrix::t() instead of just t()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580935/when-writing-an-r-package-that-uses-the-matrix-package-why-do-i-have-to-specify)

as a workaround, and to increase the awesomeness, turn the "covmat" attribute of `int.lmer` from `Matrix` classes to standard R `matrix` classes:

```
> int.lmer <- interactionMeans(lmer.fit)
> plot(int.lmer)
Error in t.default(M) : argument is not a matrix
> attr(int.lmer, "covmat") = lapply(attr(int.lmer,"covmat"),as.matrix)
> plot(int.lmer)
```

The plot then works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Spacedman. As far as I can see, models fitted by `lmer` are of class `merMod`.

Comment: `class(lmer.fit)` gives me `"lmerMod"`, not `"merMod"`, although `inherits(lmer.fit,"merMod")` is TRUE which I don't understand because I'd expect the class function call to include both... Hmm....

Comment: Awesome, @Spacedman, thanks a lot! I'll e-mail the maintainer of the package.

Comment: @Spacedman, `"lmerMod"` is an **S4** class inheriting from `"merMod"`

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that this is effectively the reason of the bug: the covariance matrix of lmer has to be transformed into a "normal" matrix for the plot to work. Fixing that is priority in my to-do list, and I want to do a series of fixes including that during this summer. But if anyone wants to contribute to accelerate the update, you can suggest a pull request to the repository in Github:

https://github.com/heliosdrm/phia